# Changing LED intensity by changing voltage

Tags: led, led-strip

I learned in high school, that the I-V characteristics of a diode is far from linear. Until some voltage there is no current, then quite suddenly it jumps to being kind of linear, I think.

I have seen these LED strips, for instance on ebay, almost all of them are 12V. They come with some kind of power supply where one can change the intensity. For simplicity I imagine a 12V system on the primary/input side, e.g. a car, so I don't have to worry about AC curves when drawing below. My friend called it changing the voltage, when changing the intensity

I suspect that if the voltage is actually reduced the current through the diodes will suddenly jump from something (don't know how much) to nothing, according to what I learned in highschool. Is this correct? By reducing the DC voltage, I mean lowering the constant line V = 12V to e.g. V = 3V.

[image]

Therefore I imagine that what actually happens is that the voltage is 12V, but it is not constant. I goes 25ms at 12V and then 75ms at 0V. However, our eyes are not able to pick up that it turns on and off that fast, so it simply seems like reduced intensity. Whenever it is on, it is at 12V, and it draws the current it is designed for, and emits light, the at the voltage/current it was designed for.

[image]

For many purposes the discrete 0V or 12V versus the constant 3V will mean the same. E.g. a light bulb. Also when calculating energy usage it is the same.

However for the above mentioned reasons, I imagine that the constant 3V will not work for LED strips.

Am I right? Please enlighten me :)

Comment: You may be correct but it's guesswork without a data sheet and if it hasn't got a data sheet then it really is total guesswork.

Comment: @Andy: True, but... I am not interested in knowing how one particular power supply does it. I am interested in whether my understanding is correct, which would mean that a non-chopping power supply would not be a good solution, if a solution at all, for adjusting the intensity.

Answer (score 4):

LED intensty is more controlled by the current than the voltage (more electrons = more photons).  If you want to vary intensity with voltage, the simplest method is to add a series resistor that basically converts changes in the supply voltage to changes in current in a more linear fasion than the diode itself.  It is also possible to build a constant current driver using some transistors and op-amps.  However, these methods are inefficient as converting voltages, especially with linear devices like resistors and transistors in saturation, generally wastes power.

A better solution is pulse width modulation, which is just like your 2nd idea.  With pulse width modulation, less power is wasted because the drive transistors are either on or off, and when on they have a very low resistance.  There will still be a resistor to limit the current when turned on, and there may also be a DC to DC converter to generate the correct drive voltage from the input voltage.  However, the frequency is generally quite high (1 kHz or higher) to limit visible flickering.  On the flip side, too high a frequency will also waste power because the control transistors have a relatively high resistance when they turn on and off.

Comment: See that is an answer I don't understand :( How can you adjust the current through the diode? In my understanding, you change the current by changing the voltage. The voltage (together with the I-V characteristics of the component) defines the current, doesn't it?

Comment: Basically, adding a series resistor is a trick to make the overall I-V curve less exponential.  Basically, a diode will sink a more or less constant voltage above a certain forward current, independent of the current.  Adding a resistor means that changing the input voltage will primarily change the voltage across the resistor (and hence the current) while the voltage across the diode does not change significantly.

Answer (score 2):

Simple LED strips are multiple parallel segments of 3 leds in series with a resistor, for ~20mA at ~12V. Since it uses a series resistor, an increase or decrease in voltage means an increase or decrease in current, and led intensity.

You can also use PWM, as you note, because it's really an optical illusion. While it may seem it's 3V with a cheap multimeter, it's not. It's just a low duty cycle, resulting in your eyes thinking the leds are just dimmer, instead of flickering very fast.

The reason you can't supply a constant 3V, is because the forward voltage of the led diodes, especially in series. 3V just won't trigger the visual part of the diodes, but they might still conduct a few nA of current. 3V would work for a single red or orange or green diode (and quickly burn them out, typically ~1.8-2.2V @ 20mA) while it barely works for some higher Vf blue and white leds. Add three in series, for a combined forward voltage drop of 7~10V (depending on color), and you can see why it won't work (Pun intended)